# Llamaindex SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine not generating the correct SQL

Tags: llama-index

I am using LLamaindex SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine for natural language to SQL interface. My schema has one of the table called 'Suppliers' which has the columns 'Name' and 'ContactInfo'. One of the row values are 'FitLife Sports Gear' for Name, 'contact@fitlifesports.com' for ContactInfo.

On submitting the prompt query 'contact info of supplier name like FitLife Sports', it is generating the below SQL

SELECT ContactInfo
FROM Suppliers
WHERE Name = 'FitLife Sports';

Since my query has 'supplier name like..', it should not generate the SQL with exact string match in the where clause. How should I fix this ?

Tried changing the prompt but the SQL is not changing